# Is the pasted value recognized as an event object that is an argument of the onEdit function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I ran the following program to check the contents of e:

```
function onEdit(e){
  Browser.msgBox(e.value);
}
```

As a result, an empty string is displayed.

Is the pasted value recognized as an event object that is an argument of the onEdit function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This seems to be a bug.

The `value` field in the `onEdit` [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) returns `undefined` when the trigger is fired by a `paste` event. **This happens for both single cell ranges and multiple cell ranges**.

This behaviour has been reported several times in Issue Tracker:

- [Event object value returns undefined when pasting values](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141085741)
- [Installable onEdit function doesn't pass correct event.value when pasting cells into spreadsheet.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760730)

I'd suggest you to star the latter issue (which was [filed internally](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760730#comment4), so Google is treating this as unintended behaviour) in order to give it more visibility and help prioritizing it.

#### Workaround:

Use `e.range.getValue()` instead of `e.value` (or `e.range.getValues()` if the pasted range has multiple cells):

```
function onEdit(e){
  Browser.msgBox(e.range.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Thank you and I’m sorry about not investigating Issue Tracker. I have starred the issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be able to display the content of one cell when **a single cell** is edited. But if you also want to include the values of a range of cells when **multiple cells** are edited, then use [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues):

```
function onEdit(e){
  Browser.msgBox(e.range.getValues());
}
```

---

As it is also stated in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events):

[image]

---

As a proof of concept you can try this:

```
function onEdit(e){
  Browser.msgBox(typeof e.values);      
}
```

The latter will return a **string** when you edit a **single** cell but **undefined** if you edit multiple cells at once, and this is why `e.range` returns nothing in the screen.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)
I tried using getValues(). And a pasted value is displayed!

But I still don't understand.
The value was pasted on single cell.
Is a pasted value recognized as e.range.getValues(As an array has one element)?

I think copying and pasting is only case editing multiple cells at the same time. So, even if it's pasted into a single cell, the event object recognized as e.range.getValues(As an array has one element). Is this gas' specifications? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @114yusuke.abe what is your goal exactly? you want to just display the values in the ui ? or use the get the values back and paste them somewhere? Could you please clarify your goal?

Comment: My goal is treating the values(after assessmenting the values, pasting these another sheet etc...)including a case of a single cell. For the first step to do this, I want to know the contents of e. and displaying is also a debug tool of coding onEdit around.

Comment: @114yusuke.abe but my solution displays the values on the screen right?

Comment: Yes. It seems to display the values on the screen right by using getValues(). But I also want to get addresses of values. I should use e.range.getCell(), e.range.getNumRows(), e.range.getNumColumns() and so on.

Comment: @114yusuke.abe Your original question was: `Is the pasted value recognized as an event object that is an argument of the onEdit function?`: All the data you're mentioning now (`getCell()`, `getNumRows()`, etc.) was not in your original question. I'd suggest you to post another question if you need help trying to display additional information, apart from the **pasted value**,.

Comment: Thank you, Mr.Marios, Mr.lamblichus. I've been very helpful.

Comment: Mr.Marios, thank you very much for kindly answering(note that my question didn't have enough words). But I'm sorry. I think Mr.Iamblichus' answer is essential one. I accepting his.

Answer (score 0):

### Edit: jan 2022

Try this to understand how it works and how to adapt your script:

```
function onEdit(e){
  Browser.msgBox(JSON.stringify(e))
}
```

When a single cell is modified:

```
{"authMode":"LIMITED","value":"c","oldValue":"A","user":{"email":"xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com","nickname":xxxxxxxxxx"},"range":{"columnEnd":3,"columnStart":3,"rowEnd":1,"rowStart":1},"source":{}}
```

When two or more cells are modified:

```
{"user":{"email":"xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com","nickname":"xxxxxxxxxx"},"range":{"columnEnd":3,"columnStart":3,"rowEnd":4,"rowStart":1},"authMode":"LIMITED","source":{}}
```

You can therefore identify the range at any time by:

```
var rangeCoord = [e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart,e.range.rowEnd,e.range.columnEnd]
```

You can therefore proceed as you wish, for example:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet()
  for (var i = e.range.rowStart;i<=e.range.rowEnd;i++){
    for (var j = e.range.columnStart;j<=e.range.columnEnd;j++){
      // do something ... as
      sh.getRange(i,j).setBackground('red')
    }
  }
}
```

**the 'new values' are also available** by `sh.getRange(i,j).getValue()` (not the old ones)