# Apps Script works properly when data is entered into one cell at a time yet fails when data is pasted into multiple cells at once

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

---

### ** Additional information I prepended to this question **

Let's imagine I want to enter a user named Alice into my Google Sheet.

After I type Alice into A2 then Alice will also appear in B2 (with the hyperlinks added as indicated in the Apps Script).

That works. That's good.

But...now, let's say I have a text document that has Alice on line 1, Bob on line 2, and Carl on line 3. Sure, I could copy Alice into A2, and then copy Bob into A3, and finally copy Carl into A4. That would work but, that would obviously be tedious.

Of course, instead, I want to copy all three lines (containing all 3 names) **at once**. Furthermore, I then want to paste Alice into A2, Bob into A3, and Carl into A4 **at once** (with the hyperlinks added as indicated in the Apps Script).

---

### ** My original question **

This Google Sheet **-->** [Behance.net- sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rlB-MDUveSJyPK5Pw5GABaAn-ZwBTcE-4DQlCIdmWPI/edit#gid=2046852903) indicates what I am trying to accomplish.

The following information appears, in a comment I created in a drawing, shortly after the sheet linked to above opens.

When I entered in **aaa** it worked.
When I entered in **bbb** it worked.
When I pasted in **ccc, ddd, and eee** it failed.

What does “it worked” mean? For example, it means immediately after I entered **aaa** into A3 a hyperlink was created and a copy of A3 appeared in B3.

What does “it failed” mean? For example, it means immediately after I pasted **ccc, ddd, and eee** into A6, A7, and A8 all at once (that is, not one at a time) nothing happened. That is, a hyperlink was not created and a a copy of A6, A7, and A8 failed to appear in B6, B7, and B8.

The "magic" above happens with the following Apps Script....

```
function onEdit(e) {
const sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
const range = e.range;
const value = e.value;

console.log(value);

if (sheet.getName() == "RemcoE33" && range.getColumn() < 3 && range.getRow() > 1) {
    const urls = [`https://www.behance.net/${value}`,`https://www.behance.net/${value}/moodboards`];
    const richTextValues = [];
    console.log(urls);
    urls.forEach(url => {
    richTextValues.push(SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
        .setText(value)
        .setLinkUrl(url)
        .build())
    });
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, 2).setRichTextValues([richTextValues]);
}

}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. The edit event object , in this case assigned to `e`, doesn't include the value property when multiple cells are edited at once as occurs when pasting a range  having multiple cells instead of only one, so `e.value` returns `undefined`. This was asked before, i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63990938/1595451, so please show what you tried to adapt the code to make it able to handle this.

Comment: Thanks. I read stackoverflow.com/a/63990938/1595451, On line 4 of the Apps Script in question, I changed `const value = e.value;` to `const value = e.range.getValues();` yet pasting multiple cells failed to produce my desired result.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add to it all the relevant details. P.S. You might find worthy to spend some time learning the JavaScript basics, in this specific case about Arrays and how to handle them. Another example of similar questions https://stackoverflow.com/q/56445944/1595451

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to understand how it works and how to adapt your script:

```
function onEdit(e){
  Browser.msgBox(JSON.stringify(e))
}
```

When a single cell is modified:

```
{"authMode":"LIMITED","value":"c","oldValue":"A","user":{"email":"xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com","nickname":xxxxxxxxxx"},"range":{"columnEnd":3,"columnStart":3,"rowEnd":1,"rowStart":1},"source":{}}
```

When two or more cells are modified:

```
{"user":{"email":"xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com","nickname":"xxxxxxxxxx"},"range":{"columnEnd":3,"columnStart":3,"rowEnd":4,"rowStart":1},"authMode":"LIMITED","source":{}}
```

You can therefore identify the range at any time by:

```
var range = [e.range.columnEnd,e.range.columnStart,e.range.rowEnd,e.range.rowStart]
```

You can therefore proceed as you wish, for example:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet()
  for (var i = e.range.rowStart;i<=e.range.rowEnd;i++){
    for (var j = e.range.columnStart;j<=e.range.columnEnd;j++){
      // do something ... as
      sh.getRange(i,j).setBackground('red')
    }
  }
}
```

**the 'new values' are also available** by `sh.getRange(i,j).getValue()` (not the old ones)

### Edit : application to your script

I think that you can preserve the core of your script (if it works as you expect) by this way

```
function onEdit(e){
  var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet()
  for (var i = e.range.rowStart;i<=e.range.rowEnd;i++){
    for (var j = e.range.columnStart;j<=e.range.columnEnd;j++){
      myFunction(sh,sh.getRange(i,j),sh.getRange(i,j).getValue())
    }
  }
}

function myFunction(sheet,range,value){
if (sheet.getName() == "RemcoE33" && range.getColumn() < 3 && range.getRow() > 1) {
    const urls = [`https://www.behance.net/${value}`,`https://www.behance.net/${value}/moodboards`];
    const richTextValues = [];
    console.log(urls);
    urls.forEach(url => {
    richTextValues.push(SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
        .setText(value)
        .setLinkUrl(url)
        .build())
    });
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, 2).setRichTextValues([richTextValues]);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your lengthy explanation. I've been struggling to understand it.I intend to get back to you in 24 hours to 48 hours from now.

Comment: I edited the answer to show you what I imagine to adapt your script without major changes.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Your modifications worked perfectly. If you feel like it, I'd appreciate if you would add some comments because I'm unclear to how your script actually works. In particular, what does this mean `var i = e.range.rowStart;i<=e.range.rowEnd`?

Comment: That means that the row (i) will take values from the first row (e.range.rowStart) which is impacted by the change to the last one (e.range.rowEnd). OnEdit function give us the values of first impacted row/column and last ones.

Comment: Thanks Mike! That makes sense. At some point I can imagine something like Google Translate for code. Just as French can be translated to English pretty well (although far from perfectly), eventually I imagine some software will be devised to translate computer code, such as JavaScript, into languages such as English. No code/low code seem inherently too limiting to me because complex and nuanced logic is necessary to create elegant code. That barrier is inherent. But the barrier to learning a particular programming language is, by definition, a linguistic problem, not a logical problem.